# How to pass an empty parameter to oozie coordinator

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am passing a variable ${prefix} to the oozie coordinator. For testing, I want to pass **test** and for production I want to pass **an empty string**.
How do I achieve that?

```
<coordinator-app name="${prefix}Summary"${start}" end="${end}" timezone="${timezone}" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
```

Comment: I tried <space> and ''

Comment: and what did you get ? what is the error ?

Comment: Oozie couldn't parse that variable as it had empty value. Anyways, Now I'm passing some other prefix to differentiate.